# How to run a script on a terminal at startup?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a project in which I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3B+ has the latest Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). At present, my code (shell script) is running in the crontab (with @reboot command). As we all know that the script added in the crontab runs in the background, hence, I can't see the debug messages it is printing. Therefore, I'm looking for a feature or function, which should be similar to the process in which I run the code in the terminal.

By doing some research online, I found many references related to this kind of requirements. The most common method was making a **.desktop file and add into ~/.config/autostart**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=lxterminal -e "sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/main_pro/keeper_sh.sh"
Type=Application
```

But unfortunately, there is no **autostart** folder in my **./config** directory. could someone help me in achieving this task?

Comment: You could rewrite your code in Python, Ocaml, or in C, or in C++ - see [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: Write the output to a file with `YourScript > /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt` then follow the output in Terminal with `tail -f  /home/pi/Desktop/log.txt`

Comment: You want to start the script when a terminal is opened?

Comment: hello @Mark Setchell, thanks for your response, I'm transferring all my debugs to a particular file and with "tail -f" I'm able to print it, the only thing is, I've to go to the folder in which the text file is present.

Comment: Hello Aatif, sorry I don't understand why changing folder is a problem. You could make an alias, like this `alias log="tail -f $HOME/Desktop/log.txt"`